# MySQL: Is it possible to run a search on a specific database for a specific string?

Tags: mysql

I need to find a specific email address in a database.

I don't know in which table the email is set so I'd like to run a search on the whole database.
Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: It would be best if a moderator would migrate it to DBA Exchange but I don't want to open a duplicate question there.

Comment: 2 more close/move votes will automatically migrate; thanks for not opening a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to query your database with the help of the [Needle in a Haystack](https://code.google.com/archive/p/anywhereindb/) code.

#### From the author

> Sometime we need to find out a small piece of string in big Database. Like where is the configuration is saved, or where is Jon's Date of birth is saved. This code is search all the tables and all the rows and columns in a MYSQL Database. The code is written in PHP. For faster result, we are only searching in the varchar field. (if anyone needs to search in other field, he can just comment the varchar selecting part.)

#### Description

The above mentioned solution is a PHP page which allows you to enter your connection details and then just queries your database for the string.

The PHP program iterates through the tables (`show tables;`) stores this information in an array and then iterates through the `description` of each table to retrieve the columns to search.

It then performs a simple `SELECT * from $table where $column = $value`.

The standard version searches only in `varchar` fields, but this can be altered in the source code.

> Disclaimer: This is not my work and I am in no way affiliated with the author.